# When I Enabled WordPress Multisite functionality I found an error for Error establishing a database connection?

Tags: wordpress

When i Enable Multisite funcation in my fresh WordPress website I Get Error establishing a database connection error

[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/02P97.png)

I have Done all that step for required for enable multisite. it's godaddy wordpress server. that step I do in my localhost it's working properly.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message you are facing

Comment: Did you set user permissions of database?

Comment: Yes I will set user permissions.